# python openCV) videoWriter writes black image, How can I fix it?

Tags: python, opencv

This is my code to read frame from cam and save to .avi file.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print('Camera open failed')
    exit()

fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
w = round(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
h = round(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
delay = round(1000 / fps)

outputVideo = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, fps, (w, h))
if not outputVideo.isOpened():
    print('file open failed')
    exit()

count = 0

while count < 11:
    ret, cam = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        break

    #cam = cv2.cvtColor(cam, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    outputVideo.write(cam)

    cv2.imshow('cam', cam)
    if cv2.waitKey(delay) == 27:
        break
        
    count += 1

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code works perfectly when the cvtColor is in comment.
But when I remove the Sharp, videoWriter writes nothing.
How can I fix it? I want to save video in grayscale.

Comment: Perhaps it is expecting a 3 channel image. Convert your grayscale image to back to BGR or use cv2.merge() on 3 copies of it.

Comment: @fmw42 I'll try your suggestion. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: I see few issues: **1.** For writing Grayscale video, add `False` argument to `VideoWriter`: `outputVideo = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, fps, (w, h), False)`. **2.** Add `outputVideo.release()` after the loop ends. **3.** Replace `cv2.waitKey(delay)` with `cv2.waitKey(1)` (when the video is captured from a camera, the delay is determined by the camera). **4.** `cam = cv2.cvtColor(cam, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` returns one color channel.